# How to debug with strace -i when everytime address is different

Tags: gdb, strace

[b77d0424] open("etc/shadow",0_RDONLY) = -1 EACCESS (Permission denied)

every time i run [b77d0424] changed to another address

i can not use gdb b *0xb77d0424 and then c to find lib64/libc.so.6

it seems not the same mentioned in a linux programming book

after running ubuntu 13.04 in virtual box

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> every time i run [b77d0424] changed to another address

This is happening because of [address space layout randomization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization), which you can disable with `setarch -R` command.

GDB *also* disables address randomization by default, but the chance that the same address you'll get in GDB and under `strace` is quite small, as the execution environment under the two tools is quite different. You don't actually *need* to find the address under `strace`, you can find it in GDB:

- `catch syscall open`
- `run`

You are now looking at one of the `open` system calls your program does. Use `continue` until you stop at the one you are interested in. Now use `info registers` to find the address of the first parameter, and set a watchpoint on that address.

Comment: How to use GDB to break at system call: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8235436/how-can-i-monitor-whats-being-put-into-the-standard-out-buffer-and-break-when-a How to disable ASLR: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11238457/disable-and-re-enable-address-space-layout-randomization-only-for-mysef