# Difference between write() and printf()

Tags: unix, io, operating-system, system-calls

Recently I am studying operating system..I just wanna know:

What’s the difference between a system call (like `write()`) and a standard library function (like `printf()`)?

Answer (score 95, accepted):

A system call is a call to a function that is not part of the application but is inside the kernel. The kernel is a software layer that provides you some basic functionalities to abstract the hardware to you. Roughly, the kernel is something that turns your hardware into software.

You always ultimately use `write()` to write anything on a peripheral whatever is the kind of device you write on. `write()` is designed to **only** write a sequence of bytes, that's all and nothing more. But as `write()` is considered too basic (you may want to write an integer in ten basis, or a float number in scientific notation, etc), different libraries are provided to you by different kind of programming environments to ease you.

For example, the C programming langage gives you `printf()` that lets you write data in many different formats. So, you can understand `printf()` as a function that convert your data into a formatted sequence of bytes and that calls `write()` to write those bytes onto the output. But C++ gives you `cout`; Java `System.out.println`, etc. Each of these functions ends to a call to `write()` (at least on POSIX systems).

One thing to know (important) is that such a system call is costly! It is not a simple function call because you need to call something that is outside of your own code and the system must ensure that you are not trying to do nasty things, etc. So it is very common in higher print-like function that some buffering is built-in; such that write is not always called, but your data are kept into some hidden structure and written only when it is really needed or necessary (buffer is full or you really want to see the result of your print).

This is exactly what happens when you manage your money. If many people gives you 5 bucks each, you won't go deposit each to the bank! You keep them on your wallet (this is the **print**) up to the point it is full or you don't want to keep them anymore. Then you go to the bank and make a big deposit (this is the **write**). And you know that putting 5 bucks to your wallet is much much faster than going to the bank and make the deposit. The bank is the kernel/OS.

Comment: So `write()` deposits every 5 bucks in the bank directly while `printf()` waits until the buffer collected many stuff. This is why `printf()` might produce weird outputs when parent and child processes are trying to print stuff on the peripheral. Isn't that so?

Comment: Exactly! You understand it well.

Comment: The last paragraph actually explains very nicely general idea of the difference among unbuffering and buffering.

Comment: I am doing programming for an embedded device. I flash cross compiled c code to the device that has no OS. Could calling write function lead to undefined behaviour on the device?

Comment: @mercury0114 not necessarily, if a write function is available in your code it will be called.

Answer (score 3):

System calls are implemented by the operating system, and run in kernel mode. Library functions are implemented in user mode, just like application code. Library functions might invoke system calls (e.g. `printf` eventually calls `write`), but that depends on what the library function is for (math functions usually don't need to use the kernel).

Answer (score 0):

System Call's in OS are used in interacting with the OS. E.g. Write() could be used something into the system or into a program.

While Standard Library functions are program specific, E.g. printf() will print something out but it will only be in GUI/command line and wont effect system.

Sorry couldnt comment, because i need 50 reputation to comment.

EDIT: Barmar has good answer

Answer (score 0):

I am writing a small program. At the moment it just reads each line from stdin and prints it to stdout. I can add a call to write in the loop, and it would add a few characters at the end of each line. But when I use printf instead, then all the extra characters are clustered and appear all at once, instead of appearing on each line.

It seems that using printf causes stderr to be buffered. Adding `fflush(stdout);` after calling printf fixes the discrepancy in output.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to mention another point that the `stdio` buffers are maintained in a process’s user-space memory, while system call `write` transfers data directly to a kernel buffer. It means that if you `fork` a process after `write` and `printf` calls, flushing may bring about to give output three times subject to line-buffering and block-buffering, two of them belong to `printf` call since `stdio` buffers are duplicated in the child by `fork`.

Answer (score 0):

`printf()` is one of the APIs or interfaces exposed to user space to call functions from C library.

`printf()` actually uses `write()` system call. The `write()` system call is actually responsible for sending data to the output.