# why we use unix system interface in c programming?

Tags: c, unix

there is a part about UNIX system functions in R&K C programming guide.

there are system calls like `read()`, `write()`, `open()` or etc ,while we can use `scanf()`, `printf()`, `fopen()`  or other c library functions to do the same work.

so what do we need C library functions instead of them?

why do we need to know and use UNIX system functions in C programming while we  have that functions in C library?

Comment: Sentences start with a capital letter. Also I have a counter question. Why do you want to know less stuff? That sounds like a flawed way of thinking.

Answer (score 4):

The functions from the standard library provide your program an *operating system independent* interface to have the system perform tasks for you. So they are not UNIX specific, although they first appeared with many UNIX implementations because that was the de-facto operating system in those days (not counting IBM360, Honeywell GCOS, and other mainframe/mini OS-es).

Comment: This answers why library functions may be preferred, but how does this answer OP's question, "why do we need to know and use UNIX system functions in C programming?"

Comment: @DavidBowling For one reason, there are things you can't do in strictly-conforming C code - like determine the size of a file.

Answer (score 2):

Unix has system calls like `write()` that are used by library function like `printf()` for formatted and more comfortable usage. `printf()` is using `write()` in a certain fashion, and sometimes we would like to use it in another way, that's why it would be helpful to also be familiar with those `read(), write()` and`open()`. That said, most of the time, `printf()` will be the more suitable choice for writing ,instead of `write()`.

Also, read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21084218/difference-between-write-and-printf)

Comment: UNIX is written by C language.how is it possible that printf() uses write() function?

Comment: @arianpress `how is it possible that printf() uses write() function?` By implementing the parts of the OS that support `printf()` without using the `printf()` function. I'll admit that is a very short summary, but it's close enough to help understand how it's done.

Answer (score 0):

Functions `read, write, ...` are more primitive and provide direct reading/writing to OS. `fread, fwrite, ...` implement a more convenient buffered interface to those primitive functions. However, the convenience costs something. For example asynchronous input/output is not available for those functions. Also there is no equivalent to `select`. If you need those functionalities, you don't have the choice.