# Make XCode break on any console output

Tags: xcode, printf, xcode4.5, breakpoints

I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1538463/how-can-i-put-a-breakpoint-on-something-is-printed-to-the-terminal-in-gdb) which explains how to setup a conditional breakpoint in order to break on any printf function.
What is the procedure to achieve something similar in XCode ? The purpose being obviously the debugger to stop when and where something tries to output anything in the console.

Answer (score 7):

You could add a breakpoint in NSLog using lldb console like this:

```
breakpoint set -n NSLog
```

You basically have to pause execution, write that command in the console and then resume the execution.
For step-by-step instructions and a way to reuse the command have a look [here](http://cocoaexposed.com/post/40480356516/set-breakpoints-for-specific-methods-or-functions).